# Intel S2600CP4 Server build, Will not boot. How to diagnose?

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

I have built a server using this motherboard, upon pressing the power button the fans whur up and lights come on but immediately turn off.

There are no beeps, and I have tried a different PSU. I have also tested this with just one Xeon. Also, I have tried with a single stick of RAM

Is this just a dead motherboard? or is there something else I can try

Other specs:

Intel **Xeon E5-2603v2 1.80GHz x2**

Intel S2600CP4 **Board is brand new from Intel**

AIC C2KH 2U Chasis with 650w PSU **650W single PSU 80+ (standard)**

Kingston 8GB DDR3L 1600MHz ECC RAM (Tried with 1, tried with none) **(Total 16GB, 8GB per processor)**

All power connections are sat perfectly

Comment: Hi we'll need much more info.  Which Xeon CPU(s) are you using exactly? Which make/model of PSU(s) are you using?  What make/model of RAM are you using?  If you remove all RAM does POST react like it has no RAM?  Have you ensured *all* necessary power connections are inserted (properly)?  This board was released ~3 years ago, is it new (to you), or have you had this board working in the past?

Comment: Still need more.. :)  If you can't give us exact model numbers to look up, then you'll need to provide the full specs of the RAM and PSU -- specifically regarding PSU, are you using an SSI/EPS PSU (vs. ATX or another)?  Also, you say you tried with no RAM now, but didn't tell us what happened when you tried.

Comment: I've added some more specs. Its an ATX Power Supply and No RAM produced the same result entirely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Intel S2600CP4 motherboard](http://ark.intel.com/products/56334/Intel-Server-Board-S2600CP4) is of the SSI ([Server System Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_CEB)) form factor, which requires a compatible SSI form factor power supply to work properly.

So you require a [EPS12V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#EPS12V) PSU (which is what was adopted by the SSI forum).

An ATX PSU will not do the job, as it is incompatible when used with an SSI motherboard (you can use an EPS12V PSU with an ATX motherboard, but not the other way around).

Since your trying to use a 2U chassis, you'll probably need to consult with your chassis' manufacturer to find a EPS12V PSU that is compatible with their chassis (or find a new chassis that comes with an EPS12V PSU).